# Instantiating an object on Tire::Model::Persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tire

I've a very simple rails3 app that I'm trying to learn how to use Elasticsearch as the datastore using Tire::Model::Persistence but I'm having an issue with searching (you know, for search)

Here's my model:

```
class Post
  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  property :name
  property :published_on
end
```

Here's my routes:

```
Beta2::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => 'posts#index'

  resources :posts
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
class ContestsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:q].present?
      #@posts = Post.search(params[:q], load: true)
      @posts = Post.all
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end

  end
...show, edit, destroy...
end
```

My index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :query %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag :search, name: nil %>
<% end %>

<hr>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Published on</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= spot.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.published_on %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contest_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path if params[:q] %>
```

With the above, just viewing the index method with no parameters, renders just fine.  I've commented out the if params[:q] so that I would just return all posts just like a normal trip to

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

However as soon as I hit that search button I get this error message:
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}

If I remove the lines in the view to <%= link_to ... %>
Then the view renders with name and published_on text for all the posts.

If I change in the controller:

```
#@posts = Post.search(params[:q], load: true)
```

back to

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:q], load: true)
```

and remove the Post.all

then in the template I get the following error:

```
undefined method `detect' for #<Post:0x00000003a61b40>

Extracted source (around line #21):

18:     <th></th>
19:   </tr>
20: 
21: <% @posts.each do |post| %>
22:   <tr>
23:     <td><%= post.name %></td>
24:     <td><%= post.published_on %></td>
```

There's probably a simple thing I'm not doing but I can't figure it out and there's currently not a great example on just using tire with rails as the sole datastore so I don't know if this is just an obscure issue that folks run into when not using activerecord.

Comment: Did you find the correct answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Post.search{query{term :name, params[:q]}} to match a specific field or 
Post.search{query{string "#{params[:q]}"}} to match any field to the whole string or 
Post.search{query{wildcard "#{params[:q]}*"}} to match a partial string to any field